# Jest await async reject

Tags: reactjs, promise, async-await, jestjs, enzyme

I have a React component that during mounting executes this piece of code

```
this.setState({ data: null, hasError:false, isLoading: true }
service.getData()
.then((response) => {
    this.setState({data:response})
}
.catch(() => {
    this.setState({ hasError: true})
}
.then(() => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: false})
}
```

service.getData returns a Promise. I am trying to test this component. I have written some tests that test a successful getData request e.g.

```
const mockGetData = jest.fn().mockImplementation(()=>Promise.resolve("TESTSUCCESS"));
service.prototype.getData = mockGetData;
const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
await mockGetData;
expect(wrapper.state('data')).toBe("TESTSUCCESS");
```

this works fine. And if, for example I put console.log in the "then" in my component code, and put console.log after the await in my test. The "then" log comes before the "test" log.

If I try to test failure though e.g.

```
const mockGetData = jest.fn().mockImplementation(()=>Promise.reject("TESTFAILURE"));
service.prototype.getData = mockGetData;
const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
await mockGetData;
expect(wrapper.state('hasError')).toBe(true);
```

this test fails. If I add console.log to the catch in my component code - this log appears AFTER my test log even though my test log comes after the "await".

What do I need to change to fix this? I thought await would wait for the whole chain to resolve. If not then why is the success test working?
I have tried wrapper.update() - this doesn't help.
I am sure it is something basic - please help.

thanks

Comment: Your problem is that you are `await`ing `mockGetData` (but the function itself, not the promise it returns!) which pauses for a micro tick. You are not awaiting the promise chain inside the mounting callback. Your first test works only by **sheer luck** with timing. Your second test takes more steps in the component's promise chain, failing it.

Comment: (But no, I don't know either how to test this properly, only a hack with a timeout comes to my mind)

Comment: well I tried 

    Promise.resolve(wrapper).then(()=>wrapper.update()).then(()=>myexpectations) and that seemed to work

Comment: I finally fixed it using 
    return Promise.resolve(wrapper)
      .then(res => res)
      .then(()=>{
        expect(wrapper.state('hasError')).toEqual(true);
      })
      .then(()=>{
        expect(wrapper.state('isLoading')).toEqual(false);
      })

I can't quite figure out why I need all the thens but if I put the expectations earlier they don;t work. I would have expected the Promise.resolve(wrapper) to have got all of it in one go. If you can tell me why I need to do so many thens I would be grateful, otherwise thank you anyway

Comment: Because each `then` alters the timing a little bit by deferring the promise chain onto the next microtick. This is a really fragile approach, if you change your onmount handler it might easily break.